# Cakephp shell :Shell class HelloShell could not be found

Tags: shell, cakephp

I am a newer to cakephp .I config the cakephp shell as the cakephp
handbook says,when I run the HelloShell  with the command cake
Hello ,I got the error information as follows:

```
Error: Shell class HelloShell could not be found.
1#G:\htdocs\cakedemo\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(191):ShellDispatcher>_getShell('hello')
2#G:\htdocs\cakedemo\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(69):ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
3#G:\htdocs\cakedemo\app\Console\cake.php(33):ShellDispatcher::run(Array)  {main}
```

my cakephp version :

### Welcome to CakePHP v2.2.0-beta Console

App : Console

### Path: G:\htdocs\cakedemo\app\Console\

anyone who is helpful can give me a advice,plea.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

there is your mistake.
you should always be in your APP path to execute the cake console.

```
...app/>../lib/Cake/Console/cake MyShell
```

or (using the APP Console folder):

```
...app/>Console/cake MyShell
```

and MyShell should then be in `...app/Console/Command/`.
Thats all there is to it.

Comment: You are right,now I change the path to : ..cakedemo\app.and it works.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Error: `Shell class HelloShell could not be found` appear because: typo mistake or run command at wrong directory.

**Solution:**
**1.** Setup path for php.exe, cake.exe

**2.** For example, my Cake website root is:

```
C:\tools\xampp1.8.3\htdocs\cakephp-2.5.5
```

Create new file in folder `C:\tools\xampp1.8.3\htdocs\cakephp-2.5.5\app\Console\Command\HelloShell.php` with content:

```
class HelloShell extends AppShell {
    public function main() {
        $this->out('Hello world.');
    }
}
```

**3.** Open **cmd**, type:

```
cd /d C:\tools\xampp1.8.3\htdocs\cakephp-2.5.5\app

cake hello
```

We use `hello` in command line to call `HelloShell` class, because "Convention over configuration".

[image]

Reference:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-a-shell

Comment: in my case  //App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
class UsersUpdateShell extends AppShell {
public $uses = array('LoanFile');

Comment: command gives me error class App not found so I comment the App line now it gives me error class AppShell not found, please assist.

Comment: The answer existed in a long time. If error happen, it maybe cause by mismatch new software/framework/OS versions. At the present, I am not using CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you give cake folder path in /var/www/html/Console/cake.php
ini_set('include_path', $root . PATH_SEPARATOR .  'Cake' . $ds . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));

Then go to root folder. In my case the location will be
/var/www/html/
then give the shell file name; hello is my shell name, that would be
/var/www/html/Console/cake hello
 combining together 
/var/www/html$ /var/www/html/Console/cake hello

Your shell will be executed.