# cakephp Error: Class WidgetShell could not be loaded

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePHP 2.0, and my command line cake settings as follows. Surprisingly the command works fine in windwos environment

```
App : app
Path : /var/www/qa/app/
```

Current Paths:

```
 -app: app
 -working: /var/www/qa/app
 -root: /var/www/qa
 -core: /var/www/qa/lib
```

Available Shells:

```
 acl [CORE]                             i18n [CORE]
 acl_extras [AclExtras]                 schema [CORE]
 api [CORE]                             template [app]
 bake [CORE]                            testsuite [CORE]
 command_list [CORE]                    upgrade [CORE]
 console [CORE]                         widget [app]
```

I can able to see the widget [app] shell command listed above

**When I run the following command**

---

> webtools@local:/var/www/qa/app$ ./Console/cake widget

Error: Shell class WidgetShell could not be found.

```
#0 /var/www/qa/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(167): ShellDispatcher >_getShell('widget')
#1 /var/www/qa/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(69): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#2 /var/www/qa/app/Console/cake.php(41): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#3 {main}
#3 {main}
```

What could be the problem. I have gone through all the similar kind of issue [in the forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671634/cakephp-shell-shell-class-helloshell-could-not-be-found)!. I couldn't find the answer.

I really appreciate your help in this.

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting. I had the named of the file as 'Widget.php'. it works fine in windows. But in Linux/Mac it didn't.

I changed the filename to 'WidgetShell.php' it started working. I should have noticed the issue little early, spent lot of hours ;)