# Running CakePHP Shell Script

Tags: shell, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have created a shell script as follows

```
<?php

class EmailShell extends AppShell
{
    public function main()
    {
        $this->out('Hello world.');
    }
}
```

When i navigate to the *Console folder* in command line and type **cake email** i get the following error.

```
Error: Shell class EmailShell could not be found.
#0 C:\wamp\www\gitgrow\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(167): ShellDispatche
r->_getShell('email')
#1 C:\wamp\www\gitgrow\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(69): ShellDispatcher
->dispatch()
#2 C:\wamp\www\gitgrow\app\Console\cake.php(33): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#3 {main}
```

Comment: see more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671634/cakephp-shell-shell-class-helloshell-could-not-be-found/26845978#26845978

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a shell for use in the Console. For this example, we’ll create a simple Hello world shell. In you applications Console/Command directory create EmailShell.php. Put the following code inside it:

```
class EmailShell extends AppShell {
    public function main() {
        $this->out('Hello world.');
    }
}
```

Then run this command :

```
Console/cake email
```

or

```
cake email
```

Comment: thanks it worked. now when running a cron job. any idea what command i need to run for this script ?

Comment: See my answer below, or is it not clear enough for you?

Answer (score 2):

Run it at `C:\wamp\www\gitgrow\app\`. It should work.

```
cd C:\wamp\www\gitgrow\app
Console\cake email
```

Comment: This worked but this is a totally unintuitive choice on the part of the Cake devs. I'm on Windows. It works when you're in the `/app` folder and you run `Console\cake email`.  But if you are **already** in the `Console` folder and you run `cake email` it doesn't work. That's just ridiculous! Especially since they have you add the `Console` folder to the system path. ?!?

Answer (score 1):

If your shell class is in the right place, then it might be a problem that cake does not know where your app root is. You can specify this using the -app argument.

```
cake -app ../app email
```

Comment: i am running it inside the app/Console folder itself

Comment: the path also has been set in the windows environment

Answer (score 1):

See the following link about how to run Cake shells in cron:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html

Your cron command basically calls cd into the app directory and the cake command to run the shell together.