# bin\cake hello prints the HelloShell.php file as it is instead of showing the output

Tags: php, shell, cakephp

I am completely new to cakePHP and this is my first attempt at creating a shell.
Below is the output when I do bin\cake

### Welcome to CakePHP v3.4.6 Console

App : src
Path: C:\Users\ps23\bookmarker\src\

### PHP : 7.0.10

Current Paths:

- app:  src
- root: C:\Users\ps23\bookmarker
- core: C:\Users\ps23\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\cakephp

After executing the command : C:\Users\ps23\bookmarker>bin\cake hello. I get the following output:

```
class HelloShell extends Shell
{
        public function main()
        {
                $this->out('Hello World.');
        }
}
namespace src\Shell;

use Cake\Console\Shell;

class HelloShell extends Shell
{
        public function main()
        {
                $this->out('Hello World.');
        }
}
```

> Exception: Shell class for "Hello" could not be found. in [C:\Users\ps23\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Console\ShellDispatcher.php, line 327]

I tried to solve this issue using the post : [Cakephp shell :Shell class HelloShell could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671634/cakephp-shell-shell-class-helloshell-could-not-be-found)
 but was unable to resolve it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please update your question with full content of HelloShell.php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try changing namespace to `App\Shell` instead of `src\Shell`.

Comment: After changing to App\Shell and adding a <?php in the beginning, it worked. Thanks for your response!